# Check if valid url so i can pass it to an NSURL?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsurl

I want to check if an `NSString` is a valid URL so I can parse it to an `NSURL` variable... is there an easy way to do this? :)

**CRASH**
For some reason the app crashes when checking.....

```
NSURL *shortURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:data];
if(shortURL == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"INVALID");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"COOOL");
}
```

The console gives me this error.....

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initWithString:relativeToURL:]: nil string parameter'
>   2010-03-01 19:24:14.797 Snippety[8289:5e3b] Stack: (
>       8307803,
>       2419510843,
>       8391739,
>       8391578,
>       2898550,
>       3152497,
>       12262,
>       12183,
>       27646,
>       2662269,
>       2661144,
>       2454790485,
>       2454790162
>   )

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***Edit: the below answer is not true. (Apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/index.html)***

---

`NSURL`'s `URLWithString` returns `nil` if the URL passed is not valid. So, you can just check the return value to determine if the URL is valid.

Example:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
if(url){ NSLog("valid"); }
```

Comment: For some reason the app is crashing..... It works if the URL is valid, if not it just crashes ?? **code above**

Comment: Try URLWithString rather than initWithString

Comment: NSURL will gladly handle any string value except nil. That's the only one you need to special-case for

Comment: this is wrong. any string will pass as a url when using URLWithString.

Comment: Turns out `NSURL`'s handling of `nil` strings changed fairly recently, for the release of OS X 10.7 etc.: http://www.mikeabdullah.net/urlwithstring-changed.html

Comment: `[NSURL urlWithString:@"banana"]` would be valid :)

Answer (score 17):

I'm using the below method to check whether NSString testString is a valid URL:

```
NSURL *testURL = [NSURL URLWithString:testString];
if (testURL && [testURL scheme] && [testURL host])
{
    NSLog(@"valid");
}
{
    NSLog(@"not valid");
}
```

**scheme** tests the prefix of the URL, e.g. http://, https:// or ftp://

**host** tests the domain of the URL, e.g. google.com or images.google.com

Note: This will still give you some false positives, e.g. when checking http://google,com (note the comma) will return *valid* but it's definitely more precise than just checking whether NSURL is not nil (`[NSURL urlWithString:@"banana"]` is not nil).

Comment: there  is an else missing

Answer (score 2):

This is basically what the [`+[NSURLConnection canHandleRequest:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlconnection/1413072-canhandlerequest?language=objc) method does. This method runs a preflight check against an `NSURLRequest` to make sure the request is resolvable. To quickly check a particular URL, you can do this:

```
BOOL isValidURL = [NSURLConnection canHandleRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://example.com"]];
```